# MASM - Find browser window title?

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm, masm32

I have a Webbrowser implemented into my application, is there any way to find the title of the currently loaded document in the Webbrowser ?

What I am trying to achieve is that the browser reloads the website until the document reaches a specific title.

Comment: Is there any API the browser provides for you to call?

Comment: I'm using wininet API, does it have something like this ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to parse the HTML to find out the title?

Answer (score 0):

You implemented the IE browser com object in your application ?
If so, you can get the "IHTMLDocument2" interface pointer and call the "get_title" to obtain the title string. Alternatively you can also get the html source from the "IHTMLDocument3" interface and parse it youself.

refer: [Retrieve HTML source from CHtmlView (visual studio 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719345/retrieve-html-source-from-chtmlview-visual-studio-6)